# DAQmx Physical Channel variable to DAQmx Start Trigger source

Tags: labview, nidaqmx

I have LV application, where user can specify input and output channels for connected DAQ device. I want to synchronise both channels using trigger on the input channel, with analog output start as a trigger source ([image on this site](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-3882) shows part of what I am trying to do).

My problem is that user specifies only IO channels, but how can I switch from a `DAQmx Physical Channel` (e.g. `cDAQ1Mod4/ao0`) line into `source` for the `DAQmx Start Trigger` block (probably `/cDAQ1Mod4/ao0/StartTrigger` in this case, but I am not sure) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer, but I am not really happy with this way of solving a problem. I have to scan whole devices tree and compare channel or module names available for each device with the name of my selected channel ... simple channel property would be easier, but haven,t found any property which could give me what I need.